# How to format the group header in united list?

Tags: javascript, list, grouping, datetime-format, webix

I'm creating the grouped and sorted list (webix unitlist). Here's my simplified code:

```
webix.ui({
  view:"unitlist",  
  width:400,
  scheme:{
    $sort:{
      by:"year", // year:new Date()
      dir: 'asc',
      as:'date'
    }
  },
  uniteBy:"#year#",
  data:dates
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/h2cvqdy8/)

Sorting works well, but is there a way to modify the name of the group? For now it represents just a raw Date object. Any suggestions are appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, the uniteBy property will work as a template. So, depending on what you want, you can just do something like :

```
uniteBy:"Year : #year.getFullYear()#",
```

Comment: Logar is true, uniteBy is a template. You can also use a function : `uniteBy:function(obj){return obj.year.getFullYear();}`
Updated snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/h2cvqdy8/1/